# Each refresh adds another listener to socket.io connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, real-time

I have a setup with with the server listening to the clients, then sending them realtime notifications. The server code looks like this:

```js
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8888);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
 socket.emit('connected', { connected: true });
 console.log("New user " + socket.id);
  
   socket.on('ready for data', function (data) {
  pg_client.on('notification', function(content) {
          socket.broadcast.to('ROOM').emit('update', content)
    });
  });
});
```

Whenever a notification comes in from the DB, all clients in `ROOM` get the message. This works, but if a client refreshes their page, they are now listening twice, and get two notifications for each update. `socket.id`'s get added but never go away. Here is the client code:

```js
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://IP:8888')
socket.on('connected', function (data) {
 socket.emit('ready for data', {});
});

// Triggered by an addChannel function
socket.emit('add room', {room: 'ROOM'})

socket.on('update', function(data) {
  // This gets hit multiple times per update, depending on the number of client refreshes 
})
```

I've tried substituting `once` for `on` in both the client and the sever side with no luck. This causes only the first update to come through, and no others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like every time a new socket connects, you are creating a new event handler for this:

```
pg_client.on('notification', ...)
```

Thus, those event handlers will accumulate as you add one every time a new page connects.  That could explain the behavior you see upon page refresh since every refresh is the same as a new page connecting.  That event handler should be registered just once at your server initialization, not every time a new socket connects.  You could just move it out of the socket connection handler like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8888);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('connected', { connected: true });
    console.log("New user " + socket.id);

    socket.on('ready for data', function (data) {
  });
});


pg_client.on('notification', function(content) {
    io.to('ROOM').emit('update', content)
});
```

Comment: This leads to the error `socket is not defined` because we no longer have `socket` outside the callback. EDIT: Maybe you could iterate over all connected clients, but unless I'm missing something this is tricky with socket.io.

Comment: @BonnieScott - Change `socket.broadcast.to()` to `io.to()`.